# Maple: having an array of length=L how to create arrays with all possible permutation with out repetition?

Tags: permutation, maple

So we have an array x:=[a,b,c]. all  its possible permutation with out repetitions are `[a,c,b], [b,c,a], [b,a,c], [c,a,b], [c,b,a]`. How to create some vector that will hold initial x and all its  permutation with out repetitions in maple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the combinat lib.

```
with(combinat)
permute([a,c,b]);
```

[combinat - permute, maplesoft.com](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=combinat/permute)